# What is a Cheaper, more pragmatic way to store Synced Data for a UWP App?

Tags: sql, xml, database, uwp

I am building a UWP app that targets both x86, x64 and ARM platforms. I want to replace the current implementation that uses Azure for the backed (an App Service and an SQL Server) because of the high price and because my Pay-As-You-Go subscription does not allow me to set a spending limit.

I thought about using a local database but I don't know if that could be a solution since I want the user to be able to have his data synced on both PC and phone for example. I am also ok with renouncing the idea of a structured database in favor of structured files (like xml) if I can find a way to keep them somewhere in the cloud (and then I can read/write them from the client app - no need for App Service).

Are there any free, non-trial alternatives to Azure? Or should I look more into the file storage implementation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully migrated to another cloud platform: **Heroku**. In my opinion, at least for small apps, Heroku offers the best solution both technology-wise and price-wise.

I am now able to have a webservice hosted for **free** in the cloud, without worring about traffic and number of requests. Of course you can scale up if you want better performance, but you can start with a free plan. Also, I have a postgressql db hosted also in the cloud, also for free (up until 10 000 records, and it will be just 9$/month if I want to upgrade to 10 milion). One can never found an offer like this free on Azure.

I had to learn a bit of Node.js (there are a lot of languages Heroku supports for backend services, but .Net is not one of them) but it was totally worth it!

Another option that is now starting to gain more and more popularity is FireBase. I will certantly also check that out for my future apps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Azure you could use another web hosting solution to publish you API. Azure also offers small free plans that might be sufficient.

An alternative would be to request access and store/sync data to user's OneDrive. Each logged in user with Microsoft Account should have OneDrive storage available so this is a good middle-ground, which is still free for you. A nice introduction to this can be found in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632271.aspx).

UWP also offers [`RoamingFolder`](https://www.google.cz/amp/s/blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/03/getting-started-with-roaming-app-data/amp/) where you can store small files that are synced across the devices that you use. Unfortunately this is less reliable because you are not able to control when the sync happens and cannot resolve conflicts.